# Find everything installed since server creation

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, users, find, filter

I often seem to be dealing with "almost virgin" Linux installations: VMs that were created for a purpose, used briefly, but after a while we're not sure exactly what's on it.

What I'd like to be able to do is quickly (in keystrokes, if not time) get a quick picture of what's happened on a box since creation. Basically that would mean:

1. Packages installed since initial server creation
2. Folders and files created by users (especially in places like /usr/local, but they could really be anywhere).

I'm not sure how to do either of these things. Particularly the 2nd one: what would be a good way to distinguish between files created as a normal part of system activity (logs, pid files...) and those that a user had expressly created?

I tried this*:

```
find / -printf '%p %u\n' 2>/dev/null | grep -E `users | tr ' ' '|'`
```

But that turns up a lot of uninteresting stuff in /proc. I guess I could narrow the search to just /home and /usr, but that might be too prescriptive.

Suggestions? Better ways?

Comment: The VMs are almost all either RHEL or Ubuntu, btw.

Comment: If you are going to narrow your search, I think `/etc`, and `/var` would probably be far more interesting locations, if you are generally using packages.  Almost everything needs to start, which almost always means there is a script either /etc or in a crontab (/var/spool/crontab).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "files created by the user"?  If you're talking about anything they could possibly create (including stuff in their home directories) this becomes a pretty daunting challenge...

Comment: Let's imagine you created a VM, installed some stuff, did some development work, and configured a few things: Apache, SSH, a bit of Python, etc. And now you want to know everything you did. Not to 100% degree of certainty, but a pretty clear idea: X files in their home directory, Y apps under /usr/local, Z conf files under /etc/httpd/... etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest (and most robust) way I can think of:

1. Install [radmind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radmind/) or [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) or something along those lines.
2. Create a baseline.
3. Run the tool against that baseline at some later point to see what changed (and if you're using 1radmind`, to optionally revert the changes).

Note that part of (2) is identifying things that you don't care about (things in `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/tmp`, log files, etc.) -- Expect to spend some time on this.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but step 2 doesn't really work, as the VMs aren't under my control. Is there no way to work out what's happened "since server creation" without explicitly running a baseline at that point?

Comment: Not really -- Detecting changes with either radmind or tripwire requires that you have a baseline (made against a virgin system) to work against.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a look like [Blueprint](http://devstructure.com/) to reverse-engineer your systems. By default, it wil pick up package differences and config file changes. It's heavier than a few keystrokes, but is another option.

Comment: Giving this a go atm. Easy to install and run, but it's showing less changes than I expected, perhaps because I ran the baseline without root.

Comment: My understanding of Blueprint is that it only tells you what changed in *files managed by the package management system*, which could explain why you're not seeing as many changes as you expect.  I could also be entirely wrong though (I've never used Blueprint, only paged through the docs briefly) -- @ewwhite probably knows for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a timestamp of when the box was 'finished installing' (maybe from /var/log/dpkg.log?) you could do a `find` and find files that have been modified since then.

Comment: This works in most cases -- Only thing to be aware of is root can change timestamps (If the "users" are plain vanilla users there should be no issue, otherwise paranoia dictates using something that checksums files)

Comment: Well, paranoia is not really an issue - I'm assuming whoever has worked on the system was acting in good faith and isn't doing anything too crazy.